# matlab draw a graph from the incidence matrix

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, gplots

Is there a way to draw a graph from the Incidence matrix.
By graph I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics) not a plot.

Up till now I found only how to convert incidence matrix to a adjacency matrix.
In R this is possible with an `igraph` library. So is there an easy way to do it in matlab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `gplot`:

```
k = 1:30;
[B,XY] = bucky;
gplot(B(k,k),XY(k,:),'-*')
axis square
```

This function is commonly used in machine learning problems. While searching up I've seen an [implementation for weighted graph plotting](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24035-wgplot-weighted-graph-plot-a-better-version-of-gplot/content/wgPlot/wgPlot.m).

[image]
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html

**EDIT:**

```
dt = 2*pi/10;
t = dt:dt:2*pi;
x = cos(t); y = sin(t);
A = ones(10);
gplot(A,[x' y']);
A = ones(3,3);
gplot(A,[x' y']);
a = [0 1 1; 1 0 0; 1 1 0];
gplot(a,[x' y'] ,'-*');
```

All you have to do is make sure the `XY` plane has sufficient (x,y) pairs for each node in your graph.

Here is A's `gplot`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

***GRAPHS WITH ARROWS***

All the previous replies are dealing with graphs without taking into account if the graph is direct or not. I mean, it is possible that if there is an edge (i,j) the edge (j,i) is not there. To take into account this, through the following code:

```
% This figure will be used to plot the structure of the graph represented
% by the current A matrix.
figure

dt = 2*pi/N_robots;
t = dt:dt:2*pi;
x = cos(t); y = sin(t);

agents=[       2    2.5;
               0.5  2.0;
               0.5  1.0;
               2.0  0.5;
               3.5  1.0;
               3.5  2.0;];

agents = p0;       

agents = [x' y'];

% plot(agents(:,1),agents(:,2),'s','MarkerSize', 20, 'MarkerFaceColor', [1 0 1])
grid on
%xlim([0 4])
%ylim([0 3])
hold on
index=1;
% The following prints the non-directed graph corresponding to the A matrix
for i=1:N_robots
    for j=index:N_robots
        if A(i,j) == 1
            arrowline(agents([i j],1),agents([i j],2),'arrowsize',600);          
%             plot(agents([i j],1),agents([i j],2),'--','LineWidth',2.5);
        end
    end
end
set(gca,'FontSize',fontsize2)

title('Structure of the Graph','interpreter', 'latex','FontSize', 18)
```

You can have the following result:
[image]

**This is working for sure for 6 agents for now. I didn't have time to test for a generic number of agents, but in principle it should work. You could use a different agents vector to do that.**

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solutionthat uses a matrix like your a

```
% Define a matrix A.
A = [0 1 1 0 ; 1 0 0 1 ; 1 0 0 1 ; 0 1 1 0];

% Draw a picture showing the connected nodes.
cla
subplot(1,2,1);
gplot(A,[0 1;1 1;0 0;1 0],'.-');
text([-0.2, 1.2 -0.2, 1.2],[1.2, 1.2, -.2, -.2],('1234')', ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center')
axis([-1 2 -1 2],'off')

% Draw a picture showing the adjacency matrix.
subplot(1,2,2);
xtemp=repmat(1:4,1,4);
ytemp=reshape(repmat(1:4,4,1),16,1)';
text(xtemp-.5,ytemp-.5,char('0'+A(:)),'HorizontalAlignment','center');
line([.25 0 0 .25 NaN 3.75 4 4 3.75],[0 0 4 4 NaN 0 0 4 4])
axis off tight
```

Taken from the example about bucky
http://www.mathworks.nl/products/matlab/examples.html;jsessionid=59c5cf7261bdf09589f79bab2bc2?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/buckydem.html